# MySQL replace function not specific enough

Tags: mysql, function, replace

```
 UPDATE `link_tag`
 SET `TagID` = replace(TagID, 2, 13)
```

I'm specifically only trying to replace 2 with 13. When I use the above for example 202 becomes 13013 because it is replacing both instances of 2 within the number 202. I only want to replace just 2 with 13, not 2 within other larger numbers.

Comment: please show sample data

Comment: MySQL has no built in regex replacement support, and this could be very tricky.

Comment: What is the data type of TagID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a where clause, you'll only update the results that match the exact clause so you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE `link_tag`
SET `TagID` = replace(`TagID`, 2, 13)
WHERE `TagID` = 2
```

Now it'll only change the 2 where the TagID is actually equal to 2

A better way would be doing this:

```
UPDATE `link_tag` SET `TagID` = 13 WHERE `TagID` = 2
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Could you elaborate as to why not ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the problem OP has though, he only wants to change a single "2" if that's the exact value of the column, he doesn't want a column "22" to become "1313"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's not a problem, but I address the last sentence of the OP's post, where he explicitly states that this is his intention :)